# Exception in ZXingBarcodeImageView when removing from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm using an `ObservableCollection<BarcodeInfo>` as `ItemsSource` of a `ListView` to generate `ViewCells`. A Cell contains 2 `Labels` and a `ZXingBarcodeImageView` with bindings to my `BarcodeInfo`-class, everything works as expected.

Now I've to remove several cells from the `ListView`, but as soon as I try to do so, I get the following Exception from the `ZXingBarcodeImageView`

> System.ArgumentException: Found empty contents

Here's my XAML

```
<ListView RowHeight="50">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <zxing:ZXingBarcodeImageView
                        BarcodeFormat="{Binding Format}"
                        BarcodeOptions="{Binding Options}"
                        BarcodeValue="{Binding Text}"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Margin="5"
                        Grid.Column="0"/>

                    <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                              Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                             LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                             VerticalOptions="End"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Format}"
                             VerticalOptions="End"
                             LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And the Class for `ObservableCollection<BarcodeInfo> _barcodeCollection;` in the  of the ListView

```
public class BarcodeInfo
{
    public string Text
    { get; set; }

    public string Detail
    { get; set; }

    public BarcodeFormat Format
    { get; set; }

    public EncodingOptions Options
    { get; set; }
}
```

The Exceptions happens as soon as I try

```
_barcodeCollection.RemoveAt(i);
```

I've implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and tried to set all properties to null which works without exception, but the ZXingBarcodeImageView is not clearing the barcode-image and the Exception is still thrown if I try to remove the Item from the Collection. I'm at a point where I've no more ideas.

I hope anybody can help me.

**Update**
Because the `i` seems to be confusing here's the loop I'm using it

```
for (int i = 0; i < _barcodeCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var response =
        await _serverUrl.PostUrlEncodedAsync(
            new { barcode = _barcodeCollection[i].Text })
            .ReceiveString();

    if (string.Equals(response, "ok", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        percentage += progressSteps;

        _barcodeCollection.RemoveAt(i); //EXCEPTION!!!

        i--; // index must be checked twice else one element will be skipped

        await UploadProgress.ProgressTo(percentage, 250, Easing.Linear);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `i`? Is it not the case when you have removed all the elements and you are trying to still remove something from the collection.

Comment: `i` is part of a for loop `for(int i = 0; i < _barcodeCollection.Count; i++)` inside are things I check and if true i try to remove the element

Comment: Do not increment `i` after `RemoveAt(i)`.

Comment: @Clemens I dont. I've checked, the index is always the index I need and is still available in the collection. The object at index `i` is never null also

Comment: You don't in the `i++` part of the for loop? You should probably add the code of that loop to your question, so we can get an idea of what you're actually doing.

Comment: @Clemens done. The url part should be ignored here, has nothing to do with the problem I've

Answer (score 2):

Not a straightforward solution, but the easiest workaround I've found was to provide `FallbackValue` when binding `BarcodeValue`

```
<forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView BarcodeFormat="{Binding Format}" 
                             BarcodeValue="{Binding Content, FallbackValue='1'}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to identify the cause of the problem, it is a side effect of the way that the ListView is refreshed when the elements are removed and the ListViewCachingStrategy is set to RetainElement (the default).
The custom renderer OnElementPropertyChanged is called when the items are removed from the collection, and the regenerate() method in the ZXing custom renderer crashes.
This can be solved by setting the ListViewCachingStrategy to RecycleElement, this will work with Android, however there is still a problem with iOS 10, which does not correctly support a listview with ListViewCachingStrategy set to RecycleElement, iOS 10 currentlly works only with ListViewCachingStrategy set to RetainElement, this can be accommodated if you create a custom control in your portable code eg:

```
public class MyZXingBarcodeImageView : ZXingBarcodeImageView
    {
    //THERE IS NO CODE REQUIRED HERE
    }
```

And then create your own custom renderer based on the ZXing source, but replace the void regenerate() method with the following:

```
void regenerate()
    {
        if(formsView != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formsView.BarcodeValue) )
        {
            var writer = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter();

            if(formsView != null && formsView.BarcodeOptions != null)
                writer.Options = formsView.BarcodeOptions;
            if(formsView != null && formsView.BarcodeFormat != null)
                writer.Format = formsView.BarcodeFormat;

            var value = formsView != null ? formsView.BarcodeValue : string.Empty;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                var image = writer.Write(value);

                imageView.Image = image;

                });

        }
    }
```

The change is in the very first If statement, changing from testing for null string to string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace

You do NOT have to create a custom renderer for Android if you use ListViewCachingStrategy set to RecycleElement, the base renderer for ZXingBarcodeImageView will be used without error.